# Ext JS 4: Title Bar buttons not fully visible in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, tbar

The default ExtJS configuration doesn't allow title bar buttons to show correctly in IE 8.  I have not tested in IE 9.  How can I fix this?

**BEFORE:**

Internet Explorer 8:

[image]

Mozilla Firefox 15:

[image]

I've tried adding a *tbar* > *style* > *height* config of the 1st button to '200px'.  That just makes the 1st button get huge, but the 2nd and 3rd remain the same.  Even if I set the same height in all 3 buttons, the buttons are still partially hidden in IE 8.  If you know how to set the style of the tbar itself, I can attempt that.  I can't figure that out though.

**AFTER:**

```
tbar: [{
    text: 'Create HEAT Project',
    style: {
        border: 'solid',
        height: '200px'
    },
```

Internet Explorer 8:

[image]

Mozilla Firefox 15:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS fixed it in Internet Explorer!

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

    .x-nlg .x-toolbar-default {
        background-image: url(../blank.png) !important;
    }

</style>
```